# Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker

Tags: cron, upstart, services, docker

I'm using following system:

```
root@alexus:~# cat /etc/issue.net 
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
root@alexus:~# uname -a
Linux alexus 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@alexus:~#
```

I scheduled a `cron job` to check if `docker service` *IS* running and in case it doesn't, start:

```
root@alexus:~# crontab -l | grep 'service docker'
*/5 * * * * service docker status | grep -q 'docker\ start\/running\,\ process\ .*' ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then service docker start ; fi
root@alexus:~#
```

yet the message I receive from `cron` is following:

> - Docker is managed via upstart, try using service docker

and again if I ran it in shell directly, I don't get any output:

```
root@alexus:~# service docker status | grep -q 'docker\ start\/running\,\ process\ .*' ; if [ $? != 0 ] ; then service docker start ; fi
root@alexus:~#
```

Why am I getting that message via cron, yet whenever I ran it directly on shell I don't get anything? am I doing it wrong way? What's the proper way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the current [Docker 1.9.1 + Linux kernel bug 18180](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18180) which is buried deep in a Linux kernel bug related to AUFS, I was looking to move my Ubuntu 14.04 installation of Docker 1.9.1 down to Docker 1.8.3, but also have it auto-start on boot like the apt installer would have done...

So, I pulled the Docker 1.8.3 binary from `https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-1.8.3`, then moved it to `/usr/bin/docker`, gave it `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker` executable permissions.

Then, I grabbed the raw [`sysvinit-debian/docker`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e5ff643aed78fb5dfb5e3fef518dfe56b82b3023/contrib/init/sysvinit-debian/docker) script, and also commented out the `check_init()` body (it was giving me unnecessary grief) and replaced it with simply `"echo 'Skipping check_init()"` and then dropped it into `/etc/init.d`. Then I set that script to run on boot startup as root with `ln -s /etc/init.d/docker /etc/rc2.d/S99docker`, and ran `sudo reboot`. After that, I'm back running the Docker (1.8.3) service on boot, from a raw binary installation:

```
$ service docker status
 * Docker is running
```

Looks all good here - I can run `$ docker run -it hello-world` correctly now too, and keep moving until 18180 is fixed.

Comment: Thanks Mike - this got me to a point where things are running, but not sure how my upgrade path will be.  Will likely have to reinstall everything :-) but appreciate this workaround!